# Create time range based on time input

Tags: vba, time

[image: Image of time range]Greetings I would like to use a VBA to create a 30 minute time range (Column B) on worksheet "Inbound Fids". For example 1015 would become 0945-1045, 0015 would become 2345-0045. I am able to create this using the formula bar, but I have to add no less than five columns. The first added Column takes text and converts it into a time format `=TIMEVALUE(LEFT(D2,2)&":"&MID(D2,3,2))`. The second added column takes 30 minutes off the new column, `=MOD(H2-0.5/24,1)`. The third added column adds 30 minutes to the first added column, `=(H2+0.5/24)`. The fourth Column combines the 2nd and 3rd Column and converts it back to text, `=TEXT(I2,"hh:mm")&"-"&TEXT(J2,"hh:mm")`. The last column drops the Colon `=SUBSTITUTE(K2,":","")`. Can we work all this into a MACRO keeping the end result in Column B. I do realize that the format is not ideal, but we have to use military time where leading zeros will not be drop and not have a colon. Lastly, I would only want this to apply Column B where only cells with numbers are considered.

Comment: could you show a screenshot of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Thank you, I added the image. Hopefully you may be able to see the process as describe in my original question. It would be nice to achieve all that in just in a macro with the result in Column B. I would need it to ignore blank cells and where ETA is in the same column.

Comment: I am working on it. I am solving the edge case of 00:15.

Comment: Thank you so much, I've just about got the rest of what you see in the photo. I am just trying to streamline my result. You guys/gals are great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to paste this function to your vba editor and use it as a formula in your target cell

```
Function GET30MINRANGE(strTime As String) As String
Dim strRange, strHour, strMin, lowerBound, upperBound As String
Dim timeVal As Date

strMin = Mid(strTime, 3, 2)
strHour = Left(strTime, 2)
timeVal = Date + TimeValue(strHour & ":" & strMin)

lowerBound = Format(timeVal - TimeSerial(0, 30, 0), "hhnn")
upperBound = Format(timeVal + TimeSerial(0, 30, 0), "hhnn")
strRange = lowerBound & "-" & upperBound

GET30MINRANGE = strRange
End Function
```

Like so,
=GET30MINRANGE(B2)

Comment: Thank you, I always get confused with macros  especially with Functions. I think I need a Sub statement before, otherwise it will just ask me to run a Macro. It looks promising though. Any thoughts on the Sub statement?  Sorry for the hassle.

Comment: @SheridanWhiteside, I shortened my explanation because I assumed that you know the concepts. Functions are what you use in your cell formulas; they return or output a resulting value. Sub statements run tasks but does not output value. You must have a triggering event to call a Sub while Functions automatically calculate without the need for trigger. Just put "=GET30MINRANGE(B2)" to your H2 cell and see the result. (Just make sure that the vba code I gave is copy-pasted to your VBA editor.) You can change the Function name to whatever you want as long as it does not conflict with built-in func

Comment: I got it it I was thinking of putting the formula straight into B2. That’s makes sense. I’ll give it ago.

Comment: @SheridanWhiteside Do not include the double quote in "=GET30MINRANGE(B2)". Please do not forget to accept my answer if you were able to use it.

Comment: I tried you formula and it works; fantastic job! I created a macro to copy and paste the values into Column B. There are a couple things I still need to do. Isn't there an ignore blanks through an "if" statement at the beginning of the formula? Then I'll create a macro and replace the #Value! with ETA that changed with the formula.

Comment: I will. I created the macro to get the ETA back in Column B. I just need to tweak the formula to ignore blanks.

Comment: i made one little adjustment in your formula to ignore blanks, I used `=IFERROR(GET30MINRANGE(B3),"")`. Thank you.